# You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, events, serialization, queue

I am using default laravel event system like this

```
use \Illuminate\Database\Connection;

class ExampleService {

private $connection;

    public function __construct(Connection $connection)
    {
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }
}

class ExampleEvent {

    private $service;

    public function __construc(ExampleService $service) {
        $this->service = $service;
    }
}


class ExampleListener implements ShouldQueue {

    public function handle(ExampleEvent $event) {

    }
}
```

This is my custom service where i am using connection instead of eloquent and whenever i inject i resolve my service from event to listener and put it on queue i get error `You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances` . I want my listener to work with `implements ShouldQeueue` rather than creating a different job and dispatching from same listener

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @JonStirling sorry just got little excited and forgot to put context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding items to the queue serializes them.

Connection contains a PDO instance, but you can't serialize a PDO instance, therefore, you get that error.

You should implement the [__sleep and __wakeup](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.sleep) methods to make sure the serialization happens correctly, for example:

```
class ExampleService {

    private $connection;

    public function __construct(Connection $connection)
    {
        $this->connection = $connection;

    }

    public function __sleep() {
         return []; //Pass the names of the variables that should be serialised here
    }
    public function __wakeup() {
         //Since we can't serialize the connection we need to re-open it when we unserialise
         $this->connection = app()->make(Connection::class); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you no i can play with now issue just need to manage my dependencies properly